# C++: Friend method not accessing nested class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading, friend

I have the following:

```
using namespace std;

template<class T> class olsm;                 
template<class T> istream& operator>>(istream& in, olsm<T>& x);
template<class T> ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, olsm<T>& x);

template <class T>                                              
class olsm {

    friend istream& operator>> <> (istream& in, olsm& x);
    friend ostream& operator<< <> (ostream& out, olsm& x);

    public:                                
        class node {                           
            public:
        };

        ///Other stuff
};      

////More stuff

template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, olsm<T>& x) {

    olsm<T>::node* rowNode = x;

    //Even more stuff!

    return out;
}
```

But when I try to compile I get,

```
error: 'rowNode' was not declared in this scope
```

which is odd because I get the error on the line I'm trying to declare it at. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I don't think this line will work - think about what you are doing, assigning an object to a pointer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`olsm<T>::node*` is a dependent name (it depends on a template parameter). You need to write `typename olsm<T>::node*` to tell the compiler that it refers to a type (by default, the compiler will assume it refers to a member).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
olsm<T>::node* rowNode
```

should be:

```
   typename olsm<T>::node* rowNode
// ^^^^^^^^  You need to specify the member is a typename.
```